# Landscape - Why does it only effect content without effecting the paper?

Tags: landscape, layout, paper

I used the following to produce landscape layout. But it didn't produce the expected output. Then I found this in a [texblog](https://texblog.org/2007/11/10/landscape-in-latex/)

> You can also just change the page content to landscape, but not the actual page layout through the optional argument of the command “documentclass”. It does not make much sense, but you can do it:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: First Image]

---

I also found this in [texblog](https://texblog.org/2007/11/10/landscape-in-latex/)
That's why I used this code:

> Changing the whole document to “landscape” can be done be using the geometry-package:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Second Image]

---

Now everything is clear to me. But then I checked [latex documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/book/0) And I found this.

> The variables \paperwidth and \paperheight should reflect the physical paper
> size after trimming. For desk printer output this is usually the real paper size
> since there is no post-processing. Classes for real book production will probably
> add other paper sizes and additionally the production of crop marks for trimming.
> In compatibility mode, these (and some of the subsequent) options are disabled,
> as they were not present in LATEX2.09.

```latex
9 \if@compatibility\else
10 \DeclareOption{a4paper}
11 {\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
12 \setlength\paperwidth {210mm}}
13 \DeclareOption{a5paper}
14 {\setlength\paperheight {210mm}%
15 \setlength\paperwidth {148mm}}
16 \DeclareOption{b5paper}
17 {\setlength\paperheight {250mm}%
18 \setlength\paperwidth {176mm}}
19 \DeclareOption{letterpaper}
20 {\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
21 \setlength\paperwidth {8.5in}}
22 \DeclareOption{legalpaper}
23 {\setlength\paperheight {14in}%
24 \setlength\paperwidth {8.5in}}
25 \DeclareOption{executivepaper}
26 {\setlength\paperheight {10.5in}%
27 \setlength\paperwidth {7.25in}}
```

> The option landscape switches the values of \paperheight and \paperwidth,
> assuming the dimensions were given for portrait paper.

```latex
28 \DeclareOption{landscape}
29 {\setlength\@tempdima {\paperheight}%
30 \setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
31 \setlength\paperwidth {\@tempdima}}
32 \fi
```

---

If this is true, it means that the paperwidth was 845pt and paperheight was 597pt when I used landscape option. But why did the page remain same as before and only content of the page changed? The above code (from the documentaion) shows that landscape option doesn't only change textwidth textheight but also paperwidth and paperheight. Why didn't the paper change?